# Jenkins Pipeline - global pipeline library updates show up in job's list of recent changes, how to prevent this?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I don't want my global pipeline changes to show up in Jenkins list of changes.

Whenever a build is ran and there are global pipeline updates, the list of changes for that build include all updates made to the global pipeline. I only want the list of changes that the build picked up from the SCM branch that is being built, not any of the global pipeline updates. Is this possible?

Comment: Whilst the comments below are good advice in some cases - I'm leaving a reference to the underlying Jenkins issue here as the below doesn't solve the problem for everyone (me included): https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-41497?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true

Comment: Also, most of the comments here are about disabling the changelog when _loading_ a library, but OP (and myself, and others) want to disable the changelog automatically _for all pipelines that consume the library_, and the global checkbox doesn't appear to work. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65649

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Such option to disable the changelog exists since version 2.9 of the [Pipeline Shared Groovy Libraries Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin):

```
@Library(value="mylib", changelog=false)
```

Comment: there is also a way to do it in declarative pipeline?

Comment: It doesn't work from within the libraries directive in declarative pipeline - there is a placeholder in the coder from 2017 allowing for it, but it is as yet unimplemented: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/15978cd172a8d34e2cd6bf8a6bfeaa5514d44dad/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/parser/ModelParser.groovy#L743

Comment: I don't understand exactly. You're not linking to a specific line in the code. Have you checked Gerald Mücke's answer on the `changelog` parameter?

Comment: This is for a pipeline that consumes the library. Is there a way to disable the changelog from within the library itself, instead of having to go modify all consumers of the library?

Answer (score 9):

You can also uncheck the corresponding box in the Jenkins system settings if you are administrator for your Jenkins, see here:

[image]

Comment: hi, I have a similar problem:  We have jenkinsfile in central git repository with jenkinsfiles and we don't want to see changelog of jenkinsfile repo in the application job for changes of application sources. Is there a similar solution not to show that in jobs recent changes?

Comment: how are you importing your jenkinsfiles into your projects? The answers here show solutions for all different kinds of imports, I could not think of a sane way that is not covered here :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @StephenKing's response, if you use the `library` step, do it this way

```
library identifier: 'mylib', changelog: false
```

More info on the topic in [this improvement request](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41497)

Answer (score -2):

I have encountered the same problem and did an ugly workaround .

just at any change of the pipeline library put a prefix in your source control commit and then when you parse your changes you can ignore the changes with the commit prefix comment

I hope it helps