# How to get a Jenkins Pipeline build to show change history (changes) for a specific branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using a declarative pipeline and groovy scripts to check out my branch. I check out using the checkout step:

```
    [$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: "${selectedBranch}"]], 
    browser: [$class: 'BitbucketWeb', repoUrl: 'myURL'], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: 
    [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, reference: "${cloneReference}", shallow: true, timeout: 5]], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "${projectDetails.repositoryAddress}"]]])
```

And that works great. However when looking at the change history, it shows the history for my shared library NOT for the actual branch checked out. This means I'm getting all the history for my jenkins groovy changes, but no history for the actual solution/source being built. I cannot figure out a way to overcome this.

On my Jenkins job I see this:

```
Started by user Me

    Revision: 53eb41e0c05fd4cb466268947102990b2b14354e
GroovyImplementation
    Revision: 825d8201904b000f479ebc91c9d244cfb956dd85
refs/remotes/origin/releases/release-2.18
```

On the "Changes" page I see changes for "GroovyImplementation" (of which there are frequently none) but I want changes for "refs/remotes/origin/releases/release-2.18" which is where the meaningful changes are.

Similarly, on the Stage View I see the number of commits for "GroovyImplementation" rather than the release branch.

How can I display checkout information for the release branch *without* using a multi-pipeline build?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46748508/4311135

Comment: I have made those changes and it had no effect. My Jenkins is on the latest release as of this morning, with all plugins updated. It still shows the change history for the shared library, and shows no history for the branch updated through the "checkout" pipeline step. Jenkins was restarted after activating that feature as suggested in the other posts.

I'm not certain if I should make my comments here or on the other thread. The other thread seems to referring only to suppressing library changes, where the greater part of my problem is not getting the commits for the branch in checkout

Comment: so, just to make it clear. do you want the changes to be calculated against specific branch every time that job runs ?

Comment: I want it to show the changes for the branch that was cloned/compiled/tested against not the Shared-Library. In the example above, "GroovyImplementation" is the shared library and I get the changes for that. ".../releases/release-2.18" is the branch that that job actually cloned, built, tested, published etc. but I have no change history for it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the branch `selectedBranch` - what you want is supposed to be supported out of the box by [SCM step plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) (`changelog` by default is set to `true`).

However, I found it not working as well, so what you can do, is use the extension for this plugin: `[$class: 'ChangelogToBranch', options: [compareRemote: 'myURL', compareTarget: "${selectedBranch}"]]`

As you can see, `extensions:` gets an array of arrays, so you just add this extension to your existing, e.g.

```
extensions: 
[
  [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, reference: "${cloneReference}", shallow: true, timeout: 5], 
  [$class: 'ChangelogToBranch', options: [compareRemote: 'myURL', compareTarget: "${selectedBranch}"]]
],
```

Comment: To generate the 'ChangelogToBranch' line, you can use Jenkins' Pipeline Syntax Snippet Generator, pick the Sample Step named 'checkout: Check out from version control', and under 'Additional Behaviours', click 'Add' and add the behaviour named 'Calculate changelog against a specific branch'.  Then when you fill up the fields and click 'Generate Pipeline Script', you'll have the 'ChangelogToBranch' string configured for you.

Answer (score 2):

The changelog is calculated by default against a previous build, you can read it here https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin#changelog-extensions. If you want the changelog to be calculated against a specific branch you can configure your job explicitly by adding additional behavior `Calculate changelog against a specific branch`